# npm install mongoose on windows 7 failing

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm, mean, bson

Trying to install mongoose on windows 7. 
I have searched all other stackoverflow question related to my queries.Nothing works for me. 
updated the npm version to 2.4.1

If any one can help on this.

below is my error log

**From Installation command prompt**

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install mongoose
|
> kerberos@0.0.7 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\
kerberos>node "C:\Users\BARUN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

> bson@0.2.18 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\
bson>node "C:\Users\BARUN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\
\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
mongoose@3.8.22 node_modules\mongoose
+-- regexp-clone@0.0.1
+-- muri@0.3.1
+-- sliced@0.0.5
+-- hooks@0.2.1
+-- mpath@0.1.1
+-- mpromise@0.4.3
+-- ms@0.1.0
+-- mquery@0.8.0 (debug@0.7.4)
+-- mongodb@1.4.28 (kerberos@0.0.7, bson@0.2.18)

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

**From builderror.log**

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(child_process.js:802:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Users\\BARUN\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.36
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to install mongoose on windows 7

below are my findings/solutions

I found out problem was with mongodb which is itself a node module and a dependency for mongoose.The mongodb module was not build properly becasue I had not install **Visual Studio c++ 2010**. So I install Visual Studio c++ 2010 , gave a restart and tried the mongoose installation , and it worked for me.

another problem I faced is , I work behind a firewall ,because of that npm was not able to download some files , and installation aborted.

to get rid of that we need to set up proxy first before installation.

**npm config set proxy http://your.proxy:port**

Comment: A detailed installation manual can be found on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp